# Celery Worker ImportError: No module named app-core

Tags: python, celery

From the app/app-core, I am trying to start a celery worker using the command:

```
celery worker --app=app-core -l info
```

However, I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named act-core
```

I am following along with this [tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#next-steps) and also tried doing replicating the project exactly in a separate folder named proj.  First time using celery . . what am I missing?

Also, here is my celery.py file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('proj.celery',
                broker='amqp://',
                backend='amqp://',
                include=['proj.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
celery.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()
```

Comment: Python module/package names cannot include the character '-'. If the module containing the app is `proj.celery` then you can do `celery -A proj.celery:celery` to point to the name of the variable containing the app.  See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#about-the-app-argument

Comment: Thanks!  Got it working now with the proj example.